# How to import a library in puTTY

Tags: python, import, putty, beagleboneblack

I'm pretty new to Linux world and am struggling with a project with BBB (Beaglebone Black, I'm sure you all know it), I'm pretty slow on the learning curve but it's getting better.

Since it's Debian, puTTY is my Terminal in Windows, but now that I need to import a library, it can't understand `import` since it's a Python command and I have to use the shebang line.

But how can I use it in puTTY? Using `#!/usr/bin/python`
before the command in terminal doesn't work apparently right?

And when I just type:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
```

And it obviously says:

```
-bash: import: command not found
```

I'm trying to do this:
https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/using-the-bbio-library

And I have already passed this step:
https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/installation-on-ubuntu

As my list is looking like this:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ ls -al

total 44    
drwxr-xr-x 4 debian debian 4096 Dec 19 03:28 .    
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 12 21:12 ..    
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Nov 12 21:14 .BBIOServer    
-rw-r--r-- 1 debian debian 220 Nov 12 2014 .bash_logout    
-rw-r--r-- 1 debian debian 3515 Nov 12 2014 .bashrc    
-rw------- 1 root root 7 Nov 12 21:18 .gitconfig    
-rw------- 1 110 116 113 Nov 12 21:15 .npmrc    
-rw------- 1 debian debian 186 Nov 12 21:12 .pastebinit.xml    
-rw-r--r-- 1 debian debian 675 Nov 12 2014 .profile    
-rw------- 1 debian debian 64 Nov 12 21:12 .xsessionrc    
drwx------ 2 debian debian 4096 Nov 12 21:12 bin
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just so you know your links are broken

Comment: You can only use `#!/usr/bin/python` in python file, that's [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (or hashbang). If you're in Shell, I think you need enter **Python Shell** via `python` command before you import any python modules.

Comment: Thanks @wilbur. They're fixed now.

Comment: @KevinGuan if you check the second link I think I have the Python Shell installed. Thank you for the perfect editing btw.
Or I had better to ask, how can I do that?

Comment: type `python` ... then when the shell starts type `from ... import ...`

Comment: PuTTY is a terminal emulator, not the program you're entering the commands into.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thank you so much. It was a great help.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thank you I got it.

Comment: can anyone solve this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997622/python-3-4-3-modules-installation-in-linux-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [your second link](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/installation-on-ubuntu), I think you missed this part:

> You can also validate by executing the `python` command to enable the interpreter, and run the following code (you can tell you're in the right place when you see the `>>>` in your terminal)

[**Bash Shell**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) *isn't* [**Python Shell**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#invoking-the-interpreter). Sure you installed it, but you didn't run it. Check this:

```
[kevin@Arch ~]$ import sys
bash: import: command not found

[kevin@Arch ~]$ python
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec  7 2015, 12:58:09) 
[GCC 5.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>>
```

So I think you need type `python` command to enter the Python Shell, before run Python commands (for example, `import`) as I said in comments.

---

To learn more about what's Python Shell, [the document is here].

Comment: Thank you so much! I have to stop being so impatient. Now it works. Although when I use the command `python` it shows `>>>` it still can't import that library `debian@beaglebone:~$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 13:48:22)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO; print GPIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO`, but when I use `sudo` it works perfectly. Should I keep using this format or there's a work around?

Comment: @Mohsen: Hmm...what do you mean about that *when I use `sudo` it works perfectly* ?

Comment: I meant I need to run python as `sudo python`, otherwise I can't use the `import` command.

Comment: @Mohsen: Oh, maybe it's because only root user can import that module. I don't know why, but happy hear that your problem solved :)